# pd.df.groupby() events that never occur (0%)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I've got a `pandas data frame` with two columns, 'morning' and 'evening', which represent a morning and an evening pressure measurement. The values in the columns are either 'high', 'medium', or 'low'.

```
    morning evening
0   high    high
1   high    medium
2   high    medium
3   high    low
4   medium  high
```

I want to create two lists, '`pressure_change`' and '`pressure_change_likelihood`'. '`pressure_change`' describes what type of pressure change took place between the morning and the evening, eg 'high-low' is a change from a high morning pressure to a low evening pressure. '`pressure_change_likelihood`' describes how frequent a given type of pressure change is, eg if the pressure was high in the morning it went to medium in the evening half of the time (0.50).

```
pressure_change = [['high-high', 'high-medium', 'high-low'],
                  ['medium-high', 'medium-medium', 'medium-low'],
                  ['low-high', 'low-medium', 'low-low']]

pressure_change_likelihood = [[0.25, 0.50, 0.25],
                              [0.33, 0.00, 0.67],
                             [0.00, 1.00, 0.00]]
```

I've been able to create '`pressure_change`' fine, but the problem is '`pressure_change_likelihood`'. I thought I'd try to use `pd.df.groupby()` as a starting point and then convert the output to a list of lists, but the pandas series generated doesn't include a 0.00 value for events that never took place, and the order of the values is different from what I need it to be.

```
import pandas as pd 

# Data 
data = [['high', 'high'], ['high', 'medium'], ['high', 'medium'], ['high', 'low'], ['medium', 'high'], ['medium', 'low'], ['medium', 'low'],['low', 'medium']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['morning', 'evening']) 

# pressure_change
unique_array= df.morning.unique()
pressure_change = []
for i in unique_array:
    sub_list = []
    for k in unique_array:
        sub_list.append(i+'-'+k)
    pressure_change.append(sub_list)

# pressure_change_likelihood   
per = df.groupby(['morning', 'evening'])['evening'].size()
pressure_change_likelihood  = per.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: round(x / float(x.sum()), 2))

print(pressure_change_likelihood)

morning  evening
high     high       0.25
         low        0.25
         medium     0.50
low      medium     1.00
medium   high       0.33
         low        0.67
Name: evening, dtype: float64
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.morning,df.evening,normalize='index').stack()
Out[84]: 
morning  evening
high     high       0.250000
         low        0.250000
         medium     0.500000
low      high       0.000000
         low        0.000000
         medium     1.000000
medium   high       0.333333
         low        0.666667
         medium     0.000000
dtype: float64
```